# Is there any API for change existing monaco editor contruction options?

Tags: monaco-editor

I need to change existing monaco editor contruction options at run time.
Something like this:

```
editor.updateOptions({
        fixedOverflowWidgets : true
});
```

Editor version 0.24.0. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

It's [IStandaloneCodeEditor.updateOptions](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.editor.istandalonecodeeditor.html#updateoptions).

For such question best is to search in the API documentation of monaco-editor.